# Selenium Grid2 / Selenium RC - Remote Node on other System is connecting/registering to HUB but not exceuting tests

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc, selenium-webdriver, testng, selenium-grid

I have two machines. One is running `selenium hub` with complete test suit and on another I want to execute these tests, so I have run `node/rc` on 2nd machine which registers to hub as it is showing hub page "http://localhost:4444/grid/console?config=true&configDebug=true" is showing entry for it.

Problem is when I execute command to run these test from 1st machine it doesn't start execution on 2nd machine.

**I got following message many times in hub console when I run test:**

*Jun 8, 2012 7:32:56 PM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryConnect
INFO: I/O exception (java.net.NoRouteToHostException) caught when connecting to the target host: No route to host: connect
Jun 8, 2012 7:32:56 PM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryConnect
INFO: I/O exception (java.net.NoRouteToHostException) caught when connecting to the target host: No route to host: connect
Jun 8, 2012 7:32:56 PM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryConnect
INFO: Retrying connect.*

If I run `node/rc` on first machine on which `hub` is running already it executing these test as expected.

I have just migrated my test suit which was previously running by selenium RC to selenium grid.
Test is written in Java and using TestNG.

Do I also need to change something in TestNG file?
I have installed & configured `ant/java` and placed `selenium-server-standalone<version no>.jar` on second machine. Does any thing more is required?

Please go ahead to give suggestions.

Comment: Which operating system is your node and hub using? Windows/linux?

Comment: I am using WinXP on both machine.

Comment: Can you check whether windows firewall is disabled in both machines? If its not, then disable it and try again

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if your machines can communicate with each other based on your Grid config and the ports that are being used.

You could use `telnet <hostservername> <portnumber>` 
. Example `telnet node.suman.com 4445` from your Hub machine and `telnet hub.suman.com 4444` from your node.

Both the commands after running on your command line should say -

```
Trying <some IP>...
Connected to node.suman.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
```